# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(1 - \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} \Big)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sequence {$x_n$} of positive terms monotonically increasing and bounded.

How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(1 - \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} \Big)$ is convergent?

Comment: First show that $x_n$ converges to some $x > 0$. Then try to show that we have $1 - \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} \leq C[x_{n+1} - x_n]$ for some constant $C > 0$.

Comment: Good idea! Some similar [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146407/find-a-sequence-x-n-such-that-x-n-is-monotonic-lim-x-n-0-sum-n-1?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

First, since $x_n$ is positive, increasing, and bounded, the limit, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$, exists.  Denote this limit by $x_{\infty}$.

Now, let $s_n=1-\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$.  Clearly, since $x_n\le x_{n+1}$, then $s_n\ge 0$. Hence, the sequence of partial sums, $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^Ns_n$, is monotonically increasing.

Next, we note that

$$0\le s_n= 1-\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_{n+1}}\le \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_2}$$

Therefore, we have

$$0\le S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(1-\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\right)\le \frac{x_{N+1}-x_1}{x_2}\to \frac{x_{\infty}-x_1}{x_2}$$

which shows that $S_N$ is bounded above.  Therefore, inasmuch as $S_N$ is increasing and bounded above, it converges.

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: $$
x_1 \lt x_{n+1} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x_{n+1}} \lt \frac{1}{x_1} \Rightarrow \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_{n+1}} \lt \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_1} \Rightarrow \small \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_{n+1}} \lt \frac{1}{x_1}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_{n+1}-x_n) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{N}(+x_{n+1}-x_n)=\small (-x_1+x_2)+(-x_2+x_3)+(-x_3+x_4)+...+(-x_{\tiny N-1\small}+x_{\tiny N\small}) \normalsize = x_{\small N\normalsize}-x_1 \Rightarrow \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_{n+1}} \lt \frac{1}{x_1} \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(x_{\small N\normalsize}-x_1)=\frac{1}{x_1} (x_{\infty}-x_1)=\frac{x_{\infty}}{x_1}-1
$$

Comment: Greetings Mark, No question at all. I am just trying to explain your (good) answer. Thanks.

Comment: OK. And thank you!   Much appreciative.  Of course feel free to up vote as you see fit.